# SoapClient set custom HTTP Header

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am doing some work writing a PHP-based SOAP client application that uses the SOAP libraries native to PHP5.  I need to send a an HTTP cookie and an additional HTTP header as part of the request.  The cookie part is no problem:

Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient($webServiceURI, array("exceptions" => 0, "trace" => 1, "encoding" => $phpInternalEncoding));
$client->__setCookie($kkey, $vvalue);
```

My problem is the HTTP header.  I was hoping there would have been a function named

**__setHeader**

or

**__setHttpHeader**

in the SOAP libraries.  But no such luck.

Anyone else dealt with this?  Is there a workaround?  Would a different SOAP library be easier to work with?  Thanks.

<sub>(I found this unanswerd question here http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=125387.0, I copied it b/c i've the same issue)</sub>

Answer (score 30):

Try setting a stream context for the soap client:

```
$client = new SoapClient($webServiceURI, array(
    "exceptions" => 0, 
    "trace" => 1, 
    "encoding" => $phpInternalEncoding,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => 'SomeCustomHeader: value'
        ),
    )),
));
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is the proper way to do it in PHP 5.3+ [SoapClient set custom HTTP Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179138/soapclient-set-custom-http-header/6691848#6691848)

However, PHP 5.2 does not take all of the values from the stream context into consideration. To get around this, you can make a subclass that handles it for you (in a hacky way, but it works).

```
class SoapClientBackport extends SoapClient {
  public function __construct($wsdl, $options = array()){
    if($options['stream_context'] && is_resource($options['stream_context'])){
      $stream_context_options = stream_context_get_options($options['stream_context']);
      $user_agent = (isset($stream_context_options['http']['user_agent']) ? $stream_context_options['http']['user_agent'] : "PHP-SOAP/" . PHP_VERSION) . "\r\n";
      if(isset($stream_context_options['http']['header'])){
        if(is_string($stream_context_options['http']['header'])){
          $user_agent .= $stream_context_options['http']['header'] . "\r\n";
        }
        else if(is_array($stream_context_options['http']['header'])){
          $user_agent .= implode("\r\n", $stream_context_options['http']['header']);
        }
      }
      $options['user_agent'] = $user_agent;
    }
    parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
  }
}
```

Comment: I even had to do this with PHP 5.3.10.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a situation where I had to provide a hash of all the text of the soap request in the HTTP header of the request for authentication purposes. I accomplished this by subclassing [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and using the [stream_context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) option to set the header:

```
class AuthenticatingSoapClient extends SoapClient {
    private $secretKey = "secretKeyString";
    private $context;

    function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
        // Create the stream_context and add it to the options
        $this->context = stream_context_create();
        $options = array_merge($options, array('stream_context' => $this->context));

        parent::SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    }

    // Override doRequest to calculate the authentication hash from the $request. 

    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        // Grab all the text from the request.
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($request);
        $innerText = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->textContent;

        // Calculate the authentication hash. 
        $encodedText = utf8_encode($innerText);
        $authHash = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $encodedText, $this->secretKey, true));

        // Set the HTTP headers.
        stream_context_set_option($this->context, array('http' => array('header' => 'AuthHash: '. $authHash)));

        return (parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way)); 
    }       
}
```

Maybe someone searching will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

its easy to implement in nuSoap:

**NUSOAP.PHP**

add to class **nusoap_base**:

```
var additionalHeaders = array();
```

then goto function **send** of the same class

and add

```
foreach ($this->additionalHeaders as $key => $value) {
    $http->setHeader($key, $value);
}
```

somewhere around (just before)

```
$http->setSOAPAction($soapaction); (line 7596)
```

now you can easy set headers:

```
$soapClient = new nusoap_client('wsdl adress','wsdl');
$soapClient->additionalHeaders = array('key'=>'val','key2'=>'val');
```

Answer (score -2):

The [`SoapClient::__soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) method has an `$input_headers` argument, which takes an array of [`SoapHeader`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php)s.

You could also use Zend Framework's SOAP client, which provides an `addSoapInputHeader` convenience method.

Comment: That's for soapheaders but I need / searching for a way to modify the http-header of the request that is generated by the soapclient.

Comment: Oh, HTTP headers! Sorry about that :) nuSOAP supports cookies, but you'd have to modify it to add headers.