# How to call soap api with BASIC authantication for WSDL URL

Tags: soap

> Blockquote

We are using Soap API but we can not connect to server.I am new in soap api.

We are using Code

```
username = testclient
password = tes@123
try { 
   $client=new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1,"stream_context" => $context));

   $result = $client->__call('getStatus', array());
} catch (Exception $e) { 
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

After passing header.

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    'https://test/app/uat/test?wsdl', 
    array( 
       "exceptions" => 0, 
       "trace" => 1, 
       'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array( 
                     'http' => array( 'header' => 'Authorization: Basic dGVzdGNsaWVudDp0ZXN0QDEyMw==' ), 
                           )), 
        )); 
    $result = $client->__soapCall('getBalance', array());
```

Also we have client and secret but How we can use for BASIC auth?

Where we can set user, pass and key and secret.

If you need any thing please let me know.

Thankyou

Comment: you can add an `Authorization: Basic base64EncodedUsernameAndPassword` HTTP header to the request where the username and password need to be base64 encoded first in the form `username:password`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSDL to PHP with Basic Auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219463/wsdl-to-php-with-basic-auth)

Comment: Can you please provide one example?How can we send HTTP header ?

Comment: As you already have a stream context you might write additional headers [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691848/1377895)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But we are using as you.

`$client = new SoapClient('https://test/app/uat/test?wsdl', array(
    "exceptions" => 0, 
    "trace" => 1, 
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => 'Authorization: Basic dGVzdGNsaWVudDp0ZXN0QDEyMw=='
        ),
    )),
));
$result = $client->__soapCall('getBalance', array());`

But sometime blank screen and sometime could not connect to server.

Comment: We are creating PHP Soap Api for  here: https://github.com/apibanking/ft2_java for reference

Comment: @Roman Vottner  - Can you please provide some solution?