# Having problems creating a functionin SOAP header in php

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to use a webform to create incidents in ServiceNow. The ServiceNow API uses basic authentication with username, password and an apikey.

The authentication always fails as the apikey isn't recognized correctly. When using a SOAPClient like Boomerang it works, but I just don't get it correctly in php.

The following information are in the header in Boomerang (which works perfectly fine):

```
Authorization - Basic SU5UU0RQTVI6TWFudWZhY3R1cmluZ1czYmYwcm0=

Content-Type - text/xml; charset=utf-8

SOAPAction - http://www.service-now.com/hlr_incident_api/createIncident

Api-Key - 97c97bd4-5226-43c4-9909-adee8332d1e0
```

The code that I'm using (which always fails) looks like this:

```
    $wsdl ='sns.wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('login' => 'USER',
                                      'password' => 'PASSWORD',
                                      'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

$ns = 'http://www.service-now.com/hlr_incident_api';    
$header = new SoapHeader($ns, '97c97bd4-5226-43c4-9909-adee8332d1e0');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Can you help me setting up the correct SOAP header in php?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: A `SoapHeader` is not an HTTP header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SoapClient set custom HTTP Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179138/soapclient-set-custom-http-header)